# Get all text before cursor in VsCode editor

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am working on a autocomplete extension for VsCode and I want all the text of the users file before the cursor. I know we can get all the text in the file by using:

```
var editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
var text= editor.document.getText();
```

But I am confused as to how I can get the position of the cursor and get the text before it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
  const cursorPosition = editor.selection.active;  // a vscode.Position

  // for text on line up to cursor
  // const lineText = editor.document.lineAt(cursorPosition.line).text;
  // const textBeforeCursor = lineText.substring(0, cursorPosition.character);

  // for text in the file up to cursor
  const fileTextToCursor = editor.document.getText(new vscode.Range(0, 0, cursorPosition.line, cursorPosition.character));
```

For a text in file up to cursor:

`getText()` takes a `vscode.Range` which can be constructed from the cursor position.  Just use `0,0` as the starting point/Position and the cursor position as the stopping point.

---

For text on line up to cursor:

You get the cursor position from the selection.  That variable has a `line` property that you can use to get that line's text.

And then a string operation `substring` to get the text before the cursor.  `cursorPosition.character` returns a number for the column position of the cursor on the line.

[If you had multiple cursors, you would have to modify this.  This code works for the primary cursor in the file.  It would be easy to change that - add a loop through all selections.]

Comment: Thanks, but this only gives me the text of a single line. Which means it gives me the text from the beginning of the line to the position of the cursor. Can this be modified to include the previous lines too?

Comment: Yes, easily, I'll add to the answer.   That is actually easier.